# Why is my LED light delayed in turning on?

Tags: lighting, led

I have various LED lights around the house, but only have issues with one lately. When it was brand new (a year ago) it worked perfectly. Recently the light, when switching on, has started delaying more and more. Sometimes up to 5 minutes after switching it on. Sometimes it comes on within 1 minute, but never instantly like it used to when first purchased.

Any idea what is causing it and how I could fix it?

The light is controlled by standard switch (not dimmer switch) but does come with a remote for various functions. However, I don't tend to use the remote, only very occasionally to adjust the brightness.

[image]

Comment: Please add a picture of the light in question, especially we'll want to know if it's a bulb or a puck-with-junction box, whether it's recessed & attached to the ceiling or in a lamp etc..

Comment: Please edit your question to say if this light is controlled by a plain on-off switch, a dimmer or a smart switch.

Comment: If it's an Edison base LED light, replace it (some cost just $US2 or less).

Comment: A shot in the dark (pun intended):  Try putting new batteries in the remote.

Comment: "adjust the brightness" == **the remote IS a dimmer switch**. But the remote must really be controlling a dimmer (and possibly other functions) switch inside the fixture. We can reasonably rule out the wall switch, but there are complex parts somewhere.

Comment: No need to try to provide an edit history in your question, the system handles that - just click the "edited <time> ago" link to see what's been done.

Comment: This looks like a fully integrated unit, so there's little to take apart and test or replace. Does the delay depend on the dim level? Do all 4 "blades" have the same delay? I am leaning towards a full (warranty) replacement rather than troubleshooting on a DIY site.

Comment: It sounds like a driver issue to me wether it is dimming or not the driver provides the power to the LED’s, LED’s are instant on devices but the driver is not and as they fail they can flicker, delay start, run dim or nothing based on the failure, I would look and see if the light has a separate driver module. The driver module if separate would be located in the black area where the connections are made, a photo of the parts in that area would be better than a dozen guesses at what is happening. I have not seen a remote that was required to do anything other than change the values or color.